# plt.yticks not showing inside graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and working on graphs, when i use plt.ticks it do not show yticks provided by me as np array instead it shows same old graph values at y axis.

I tried answers on stack overflow of questions related to this but still not working.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np   
pop=np.random.randint(low=2.1,high=6.5,size=10)
pop.sort() 
year=np.arange(1950,2050,10)
plt.plot(year,pop)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.title('World Population')
plt.yticks=(np.arange(0,5,1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have a superpluous `=` in your code

Comment: Where is this surplus =?

Comment: In the line that is supposed to set the ticks.

Comment: ok letme try it

Comment: I retried it and this is the error `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a52a9b687547> in <module>
      3 plt.ylabel('Population')
      4 plt.title('World Population')
----> 5 plt.yticks(np.arange(0,5,1))
      6 plt.show()

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

`

Comment: Yes because you have killed the `plt.yticks` function - it's now an array. Restart python!

Comment: When i do ` plt.yticks([2,3,4,5,6,7],['2B','3B,'4B','5B','6B','7B'])File "<stdin>", line 1
    plt.yticks([2,3,4,5,6,7],['2B','3B,'4B','5B','6B','7B'])
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax `  but when i did `plt.yticks([2,3,4,5,6,7],['2B','3B','4B''5B','6B','7B'])
` it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
plt.yticks=(np.arange(0,5,1))
```

`plt.yticks` is a function that is used to set the Y ticks of the plot.
In your code, you assign to `plt.yticks` your tick values, which has actually no effect.

You should rather call `plt.yticks` with the tick values as first parameter, as follows:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,5,1))
```

Reference from [Matplotlib's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html#matplotlib-pyplot-yticks):

> `matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(ticks=None, labels=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Get or set the current tick locations and labels of the y-a
>
> Call signatures:
>
> ```
> yticks(ticks, [labels], **kwargs)  # Set locations and labels
> ```